# self init.. vs. super init... in subclasses

Tags: ios, objective-c, init, super

I have a `UIViewContoller` subclass `BaseViewControler`. It has a method named `-initWithStyle:`. If I subclass *that* class as `SubBaseViewContoller`,
what should `-[SubBaseViewController init]` look like?

My code:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [self initWithStyle:kGreenStyle];
    if (self) {
        // stuff
    }
    return self;
}
```

In `SubBaseViewController` I don't have `initWithStyle:` 
and my app crashed randomly with the `-init` above, I checked other view controllers which are subclasses of `BaseViewController`, and they use `self = [super initWithStyle:kGreenStyle]`, and work. What's the explanation?

Answer (score 4):

A `UIViewController` has *two* designated initializers:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle;
```

and

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;
```

The second form will be invoked when Interface Builder is used to define a View Controller with a resource, that is nib files ore segues. The first form can be used when you manually create a view controller.

You can override these initializers as follows:

```
// Designated initializer
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle];
    if (self) {
        ; // your initialization
    }
    return self;
}

// Designated initializer
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        ; // your initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Note: The method `init` will not be called when created from a resource. When you invoke `init` yourself, it will eventually call `initWithNibName:bundle:` with `nil` arguments.

See also: Reference: [Multiple Initializers and the Designated Initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW3)

### Another possible solution for your problem:

One approach to provide a method to initialize a custom View Controller is to use a "convenience class method". In this case, you don't need to override the designated initializers, instead you provide *properties* in your subclass.

The convenience class method may then look like as shown below:

```
// MyViewController
+ (instancetype) myViewControllerWithStyle:(Style)style 
{
    // Possibly get the bundle and the nib name (or leave it nil)
    ...
    // Invoke a designated initializer with suitable parameters:
    MyViewController* viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithName:nibName
                                                                       bundle:bundle];
    viewController.style = style;
    return viewController;
}
```

Comment: Just to add to this, when you call `init` with `nil` as the nibName, then the `nibName` property is set to nil. In which case the runtime  either uses the views you create in `loadView` or it searches for a nib file based on heuristics described in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/nibName. Which is why if you have a `MyViewController` and a `MyViewController.xib` you can use plain `init` and it will use the associated nib file.

Comment: @Abizern Thanks Abizern, this is useful information. Thus, in order to create custom view controllers, it may be preferred to create a "convenience class method" which encapsulates exactly these details (nib name and bundle parameter).

Answer (score 2):

You should use super instead of self:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:kGreenStyle];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

If you do it that way you force just parent class to do all the initialisation which it supposed to do. And if you want to do something in init method just in your subclass you add it here:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:kGreenStyle];
    if (self) {
        // do some stuff you need to do in subclass initialisation
        // for example init variable specific just for that class (not parent class)
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I think @CouchDeveloper's criticism is off here. Cf. my answer for more detail.

Comment: @Greg I would like to apologize: My former statement that this answer is wrong, was too over-hasty. In fact, and given the base class is implemented correctly as shown by @claybridges, that is `initWithStyle:` is a proper designated initializer, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a synthesis of Greg's and CouchDeveloper's answers.
But really, it's a defense of Greg's answer.

First, yes, understand designated initializers. They are important, and CouchDeveloper
is right to emphasize this.

Second, nothing prevents a subclass of `UIViewController` from having
completely different designated initializers (preferably one) of your own choosing. 
If you are creating `UIViewController`s outside of Interface Builder, 
as it appears the OP may be doing, the primacy of `-initWithNibName:Bundle:`
and `-initWithCoder:` becomes silly.

Apple say [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW3):

> When you define a subclass, you must be able to identify the designated initializer of the superclass and invoke it in your subclass’s designated initializer through a message to super. You must also make sure that inherited initializers are covered in some way.

Given that, here's what the OP's `BaseViewController` might look like:

```
const NSUInteger kDefaultStyle = 0; // just to have something to use

@implementation BaseViewContoller

// No longer valid for *this* class.
// Should have one for -initWithCoder: too, but elided for this example.
- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil
                         bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
    return nil;
}

// New designated initializer for *this* class.
// This should call the superclass's designated initializer.
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(NSUInteger)style
{
    // use the designated initializer of the superclass to init
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil])) {
        // stuff
    }

    return self;
}

// in *other* initializers, you *should* call *your* class's
// designated initializer.
- (instancetype)init
{
    return [self initWithStyle:kDefaultStyle];
}

@end
```

Given this, I think CouchDeveloper's "this is wrong" calling out in the comments
of Greg's answer is itself wrong. This is because:

- `BaseViewController` is unseen, so we can't *possibly* know what *its* designated initializer is, regardless of its superclass.
- OP has given every indication that `-[BaseViewController initWithStyle:]` *is* the designated initializer
- OP is perfectly free to declare `[SubBaseViewController init]` as the designated initializer, so long as he follows the rules.

Finally, unrequested advice for the OP:

- Assuming those aren't typos in your original post, you should **always** capitalize the 
  first letter of class names. `BaseViewController`, not `baseViewController`.
  You can swim against the idiom is when you
  become a total badass; by that point, I'll wager you'll not want to.